# gpsread Google Sheets Protect Worksheet with Warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to use `gspread` library to protect a worksheet and warn user if they are about to make a change even if they're an editor.

In Google Sheets this is called "Show a warning when editing this range"

Gpsread has a function `add_protected_range` [Here](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=protect#gspread.models.Worksheet.add_protected_range). Via gpsread I run `worksheet.add_protected_range('A1:J10', warning_only=True)` and I get an error

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid requests[0].addProtectedRange: ProtectedRange is warningOnly. Editors cannot be set on it.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}

Removing `warning_only` returns no error but then editors are still able to edit, which is not my goal.

How do I get this to work?

Also this function only works to make the range protected. Is there a way to make the entire sheet protected?

Comment: Can I ask you about my answer for your this question? If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- Question 1: You want to show the warning when users edited the cell of `A1:J10` in the sheet. When users edit the cells in the protected range, you want to show the warning screen.
- Question 2: You want to protect a sheet instead of a range. When users edit the cells in the protected sheet, you want to show the warning screen.

### Answer for question 1:

When `warningOnly` is `true`, the property of `editors` cannot be used. But, when I saw the script `add_protected_range`, it seems that the default editors are included. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/d21e80a49cbc19e60bb4c9f00f410075a56cdfad/gspread/models.py#L1578) I think that by this, such error occurs. So in this case, in order to avoid this, how about directly using the batchUpdate method? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
ss = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = ss.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addProtectedRange": {
                "protectedRange": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": sheetId,
                        "startRowIndex": 0,
                        "endRowIndex": 10,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                        "endColumnIndex": 10
                    },
                    "warningOnly": True
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
res = ss.batch_update(request_body)
```

- When above script is run, the cells of "A1:J10" of "Sheet1" is protected. And when users edited the cells in the protected range, the warning screen is opened.

### Answer for question 2:

In this case, also, how about directly using the batchUpdate method? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
ss = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = ss.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addProtectedRange": {
                "protectedRange": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": sheetId,
                    },
                    "warningOnly": True
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
res = ss.batch_update(request_body)
```

- When above script is run, the sheet of "Sheet1" is protected. And when users edited the cells in "Sheet1", the warning screen is opened.

### References:

- [models.py of gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/d21e80a49cbc19e60bb4c9f00f410075a56cdfad/gspread/models.py)
- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [ProtectedRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#ProtectedRange)